# Show/hide content depending on the value of the text field

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How can I simplify the code to include all functionalities in one script? Creating separate scripts probably doesn't make sense :) I would be very grateful for your help.

```js
document.querySelector('#country').addEventListener('change', function calculate(e) {
const div = document.querySelector('#US');
    if (Number(e.target.value) == 1)
    div.style.display = 'block';
  else
    div.style.display = 'none';
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.querySelector('#country').addEventListener('change', function calculate(e) {
const div = document.querySelector('#DE');
    if (Number(e.target.value) == 3)
    div.style.display = 'block';
  else
    div.style.display = 'none';
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.querySelector('#country').addEventListener('change', function calculate(e) {
const div = document.querySelector('#IT');
    if (Number(e.target.value) == 5)
    div.style.display = 'block';
  else
    div.style.display = 'none';
});
```

```html
<input type="number" id="country" value="0" size="1" maxlength="1">

<div id="US" class="flag_US" style="display:none;">United States</div>
<div id="DE" class="flag_DE" style="display:none;">Germany</div>
<div id="IT" class="flag_IT" style="display:none;">Italy</div>
```

Comment: Your code appears to work, so this question really belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com. You can ask this question and they can help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by a single change event listener, and within that listener, you can check the value and show/hide the corresponding div elements using [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/foreach) and [conditional (ternary) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_operator) like the following way:

```js
document.querySelector('#country').addEventListener('change', function calculate(e) {
  const selectedValue = Number(e.target.value);

  document.querySelectorAll('.flag').forEach(function(div) {
    const divValue = Number(div.getAttribute('data-value'));
    div.style.display = divValue === selectedValue ? 'block' : 'none';
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="number" id="country" value="0" size="1" maxlength="1">

<div id="US" class="flag flag_US" data-value="1" style="display:none;">United States</div>
<div id="DE" class="flag flag_DE" data-value="3" style="display:none;">Germany</div>
<div id="IT" class="flag flag_IT" data-value="5" style="display:none;">Italy</div>
```